# Python multiprocessing with single worker faster than sequential operation

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, runtime, pool

A brief overview - I wrote some random files with lots of random numbers to disc to test the performance of python multiprocessing vs sequential operations.

> Function description

**putfiles** : write test files to drive

**readFile** : reads the passed file location and returns result(sum of numbers in the code)

**getSequential** : reads some files with a for loop

**getParallel** : read file with multiple processes spawned

> Performance results: (Read and process 100 files, with sequential and process pool)

timeit getSequential(numFiles=100) - around 2.85s best

timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=4) -around 960ms best

timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=1) -around 980ms best

#### Surprisingly single process pool performs better than sequential and at par with 4 process pool. Is this behavior expected or am I doing something wrong here?

```
import os
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.chdir('/Users/test/Desktop/filewritetest')

def putfiles(numFiles=5, numCount=100):
    #numFiles = int(input("how many files?: "))
    #numCount = int(input('How many random numbers?: '))
    for num in range(numFiles):
        with open('r' + str(num) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write("\n".join([str(random.randint(1, 100)) for i in range(numCount)]))

def readFile(fileurl):
    with open(fileurl, 'r') as f, open("ans_" + fileurl, 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(str((sum([int(i) for i in f.read().split()]))))

def getSequential(numFiles=5):
    #in1 = int(input("how many files?: "))
    for num in range(numFiles):
        (readFile('r' + str(num) + '.txt'))


def getParallel(numFiles=5, numProcesses=2):
    #numFiles = int(input("how many files?: ")) 
    #numProcesses = int(input('How many processes?: '))
    with Pool(numProcesses) as p:
        p.map(readFile, ['r' + str(num) + '.txt' for num in range(numFiles)])


#putfiles()

putfiles(numFiles=1000, numCount=100000)

timeit getSequential(numFiles=100)
##around 2.85s best

timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=1)
##around 980ms best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=4)
##around 960ms best
```

> Update: in a new session of sypder, I don't see this issue. Updated runtime below

```
##100 files
#around 2.97s best
timeit getSequential(numFiles=100)

#around 2.99s best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=1)

#around 1.57s best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=2)

#around 942ms best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=4)

##1000 files
#around 29.3s best
timeit getSequential(numFiles=1000)

#around 11.8s best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=1000, numProcesses=4)

#around 9.6s best
timeit getParallel(numFiles=1000, numProcesses=16)

#around 9.65s best  #let pool choose best default value
timeit getParallel(numFiles=1000)
```

Comment: I dont get what your error is. Ported your code to python 3.x, tested with 1000 files, results as expected: 0.31 seconds for 1000 sequential and 0.37 seconds for 1000 paralell with 1 thread, 0.23 1000 paralell using 4 threads. Your posted code does not work out of the box, looks like you formatted for posting here but did not check if it still works.

Comment: @Harry yeah, even mine works in the way it is supposed to now(updated runtime above).
_Ported your code to python 3.x_ , is mine non 3.x?

Still, the runtime for my piece is very poor in comparison to what you stated. Are you on SSD? Mind sharing your version? That would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please do not consider this as an answer, it is for showing you my code when running the stuff in python 3.x (your timeit usage did not work at all for me, i assumed it is 2.x). Sorry but i dont have the time to look into it deeply now.

[EDIT] on a spinning drive, consider disk cache: do not access the same files in different tests or just switch the order of your tests to see if disk cache is involved

Using the following code, changing manually the numProcesses=X argument, i got these results:

On SSD, 0.31 seconds for 1000 sequential and 0.37 seconds for 1000 paralell with 1 thread, 0.23 1000 paralell using 4 threads

```
import os
import random
import timeit
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

os.chdir('c:\\temp\\')

def putfiles(numFiles=5, numCount=1):
    #numFiles = int(input("how many files?: "))
    #numCount = int(input('How many random numbers?: '))
    for num in range(numFiles):
        #print("num: " + str(num))
        with open('r' + str(num) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write("\n".join([str(random.randint(1, 100)) for i in range( numCount )]))
    #print ("pufiles done")

def readFile(fileurl):
    with open(fileurl, 'r') as f, open("ans_" + fileurl, 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(str((sum([int(i) for i in f.read().split()]))))


def getSequential(numFiles=10000):
   # print ("getSequential, nufile: " + str (numFiles))
    #in1 = int(input("how many files?: "))
    for num in range(numFiles): 
        #print ("getseq for")
        (readFile('r' + str(num) + '.txt'))
    #print ("getSequential done")


def getParallel(numFiles=10000, numProcesses=1):
    #numFiles = int(input("how many files?: ")) 
    #numProcesses = int(input('How many processes?: '))
    #readFile, ['r' + str(num) + '.txt' for num in range(numFiles)]
    #with Pool(10) as p:
    with closing(Pool(processes=1)) as p:
       p.map(readFile, ['r' + str(num) + '.txt' for num in range(numFiles)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #putfiles(numFiles=10000, numCount=1)

    print (timeit.timeit ("getSequential()","from __main__ import getSequential",number=1))

    print (timeit.timeit ("getParallel()","from __main__ import getParallel",number=1)) 

#timeit (getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=4)) #-around 960ms best

#timeit (getParallel(numFiles=100, numProcesses=1)) #-around 980ms best
```